# Is there a way I can query a mysql and inner join a json data together?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Lets say I have a mysql table call user:

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ Userid ║ Username ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║   1    ║  Apple   ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

And I have a json file (`1.json`):

```
{
    "Desc": "Hi I am apple",
    "Age": 10,<br>
}
```

How can I do something like an inner join with php to link these 2 data together to

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═══════════════╦═════╗
║ Userid ║ Username ║     Desc      ║ Age ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╬═════╣
║   1    ║  Apple   ║ Hi I am apple ║ 10  ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═══════════════╩═════╝
```

Or is there a better way I can structure the database for query?

The reason for this is that in long run, there will be a lot of records and by splitting into json and mysql is that mysql can allow me to search through the data easily and only to retrieve the information when needed. Can someone please advice me is this the best better to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For that you should have two tables I assume.
First one will store UserID and Username and second one: DescId, Desc, Age and UserId. When you want information from both tables, your query will look like this: select `table1`.`UserID`, `table1`.`Username`, `table2`.`Desc`, `table2`.`Age` from `table1`, `table2` where `table1`,`UserId` = `table2`.`UserId`;

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly the JSON data can be dynamic and have multiple different fields.

One way to do this directly in SQL/DB is to use the scheme known as [Entity-attribute-value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) a model used, for example, by wordpress to store custom dynamic fields. It provides great flexibility but is not very efficient.

Another approach is to use the JSON data directly as an extra field like:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════╦
║ Userid ║ Username ║     JSON                                         ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╬
║   1    ║  Apple   ║ {"Desc":"Hi I am apple","Age":"10"}              ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════╩
```

and query the table like (for example get users with `username=user` and `age=10`)

```
SELECT UserId, UserName FROM Table
WHERE UserName = 'user'
AND JSON LIKE '%"Age":"10"%'
```

note even numeric values should be saved in json as strings for uniform handling

This is also flexible provided your JSON data are not complex or nested, but simple `key-value` pairs and using `LIKE` (or `REGEX`) clauses can be efficient

(ps this approach is also used by, for example, wordpress, using php-serialised data instead of JSON data, but same difference)